# How can I convert JSON into a list using REST.Json in Delphi?

Tags: json, list, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a JSON file like this:

```json
[{"id":1,"name":"JOHN"}, {"id":2,"name":"PETER"}]
```

I want to store this list into a ClientDataSet, or something like that. How can I do this in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo using the `REST.Json` unit?

Comment: Rest.JSON looks good, but in practice is less so, at least for me. It does not handle lists well unless the JSON is created by Delphi from a list; It has a rather strangely named helper field that contains the number of elements (I can't remember the name of it now). I think other JSON converters are better, but I can't be sure because I ended up writing my own routines. Maybe others have got this resolved.

Comment: @Dsm I know what you mean, I struggled trying to convert an TObjectList into a Json, but everytime it was added "ownsObjects" and "listHelper" properties on the json file. In the end, I had to create my own converter.

Comment: Yes, that was it. And to convert back again you need to add them into your JSON. I also had problems with enums, but I have seen a post that (kind of) resolves that issue.

Comment: Aaaaand that's why I use SuperObject / X-SuperObject.

Comment: Aaaaaand that's why I created [jsonDoc](https://github.com/stijnsanders/jsonDoc)

Answer (score 0):

Using Rest.json, i don't know but if you want to convert `[{"id":1,"name":"JOHN"}, {"id":2,"name":"PETER"}]` to a `Tstringlist` you can do it in one line using [alcinoe](https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe)

```
Procedure ALJSONToTStrings(const AJsonStr: AnsiString;
                           const aFormatSettings: TALFormatSettings;
                           const aPath: AnsiString;
                           const aLst: TALStrings;
                           Const aNullStr: AnsiString = 'null';
                           Const aTrueStr: AnsiString = 'true';
                           Const aFalseStr: AnsiString = 'false'); overload;

Procedure ALJSONToTStringsU(const AJsonStr: String;
                            const aFormatSettings: TALformatSettingsU;
                            const aPath: String;
                            const aLst: TALStringsU;
                            Const aNullStr: String = 'null';
                            Const aTrueStr: String = 'true';
                            Const aFalseStr: String = 'false'); overload;
```

Answer (score 0):

The REST client library for Delphi 10.2 Tokyo includes a **TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter** class for parsing JSON into a dataset.

Look at the RESTDemos sample project included with 10.2. There is an example of using the adapter on the *Fetch to DataSet* tab.

The code within the button click event is this:

```
  ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;

  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.Response:= RESTResponse;
  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.Dataset:= ClientDataSet;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := edt_DataSet_BaseURL.Text;
  RESTRequest.Resource := edt_DataSet_ResourceURI.Text;
  RESTRequest.Execute;
```